# Tensorflow Custom Model in OpenCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have trained new model on top of ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco for a custom data set. This model works fine in tensorflow. But now I want to use this in OpenCV.

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow("model/frozen_inference_graph.pb", "model/protobuf.pbtxt")
detections = net.forward()
```

So for the config file I convert frozen_graph to pbtxt and add it. But then I got the following error

```
[libprotobuf ERROR /home/chamath/Projects/opencv/opencv/3rdparty/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:298] Error parsing text-format tensorflow.GraphDef: 731:5: Unknown enumeration value of "DT_RESOURCE" for field "type".
```

As suggested [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10043) I try to use [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/blob/master/testdata/dnn/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.pbtxt) config file mentioned in the thread but when I use it object detection is not working properly. Incorrect number of squares detected and they are misplaced.

Is there any method to create a pbtxt config file that works with OpenCV? Or any suggestions how to make my model work in OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

Is likely that you havent generate the propper graph, after training.
You have to convert the graph like this:

> python ../opencv/samples/dnn/tf_text_graph_ssd.py --input
>   trained-inference-graphs/inference_graph_v5.pb/frozen_inference_graph.pb
>   --output trained-inference-graphs/inference_graph_v5.pb/graph.pbtxt

Then pass the .**pb** and the **graph.pbtxt** to **DNN.readNetFromTensorflow** that should work for you :)